# upload binary from api gateway to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

i was trying to create a rest api which can take zip file as input (PUT requst) and store that on S3.

I'm following the tutorial on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-s3.html

I'm getting 500 error ad the cloudwatch logs are as follows

> Verifying Usage Plan for request:
>   c2140431-1a10-11e7-9f32-0df3853848fe.  API Key: API Stage:
>   xjjd186a30/rd
>
> API Key authorized because method 'PUT /s3' does not require API Key.
>
> Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits
>
> Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage xjjd186a30/rd
>
> Starting execution for request: c2140431-1a10-11e7-9f32-0df3853848fe
>
> HTTP Method: PUT, Resource Path: /s3
>
> Successfully completed execution
>
> Method completed with status: 500

[image]

when i try the api from post man i get

> `AccessDenied`Access
>   DeniedF55D45C185A5BF11HXopfmxAxGNvmdi7PRp4c1j/wPYmGVTrkKbGXfZwofLOn7TRBPs3uFjer/2UCIktynKtGeNU1Xw=

my roles i have given AmazonS3FullAccess permission and have assigned the role to api gateway settings and the integration request.

can anyone help please

Comment: Maybe an `amazon` error `[InternalServerError] 500 `

Comment: Also try using a `post` request instead of `put`...check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273560/put-vs-post-for-files-upload-restful-api-to-be-built-using-zend-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to put to the bucket named `rest`.
Is that the correct bucket?

This documentation will probably be a little more helpful for you:
[Integrating API with AWS S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html)

In the example in used in the documentation, a `bucket` and `object` are provided in the path override for the PUT item method. These are mapped from the path params `folder` and `item`.

Here is a helpful screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I tried this, and successfully put the audio file, but i couldn't play the same, i think there is some issue with the content type!  How can i send the audio file as multipart/form-data to s3 via api gateway?

Comment: Did you solve how to send the correct content-type to s3 so that the file gets played?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload the binary files like mp3,audio, documents etc..., you can add an entry with value `multipart/form-data` in the `Binary support` in AWS API Gateway settings and post/put the binary file using the header `Content-Type = multipart/form-data` from postman or api client. It should work..!!

[api gateway-binary support image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utwAO.png)